# Dompdf - images not render in pdf

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, dompdf

I am using `dompdf` in Symfony project to render `PDF`

```
        $pdfOptions = new Options();
        $pdfOptions->set('defaultFont', 'Arial');
        $pdfOptions->setIsPhpEnabled(true);
        $pdfOptions->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dompdf->setOptions($pdfOptions);
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("mypdf.pdf");
```

I am set remoteEnabled to true but still no changes. The same image is shown on page render but not on pdf.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your action returning PDF?

```
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
    $pdfInvoice = new Dompdf($options);
    $body = $this->renderView('App/Payments/invoice.html.twig');

    $pdfInvoice->loadHtml($body);
    $pdfInvoice->setPaper('A4');
    $pdfInvoice->render();
    $pdfInvoice->stream();

    return new Response($pdfInvoice->output());
```

This way worked for me

Edit:
One more thing, set absolute path in your template eg.

```
<img src="{{ asset('assets/img/logo.png', absolute=true) }}">
```